# Adding axhline to my plot and constraining the xmax and xmin with datetime objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I have a time series of temperatures for a given location. I have done some analyses using other data and remote sensing to determine the Start and End of the forest growing season for the same location. Now I would like to impose small horizontal lines on a secondary x-axis, which display the length of the growing season. Ideally, it would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HCtZ.png). Where the primary x axis is temp, the secondary x axis is a static value for a single growing season and the y axis is the 13 year time period ploted as a datetime object. So basically, i want the same blue lines, but i want there length to be determined by two datetime values.

I am aware that axhline() takes a y positional argument (which will be the static value for the growing season), and a xmin and an xmax which must be normalized floats between 0 and 1.

My question is then, how do I normalize a 13 year-long (daily) dataframe in order to give the plt.axhline() the appropriate values xmin and xmax values.

here is the code i am using to plot the figure above

and  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt3eC.png) is the dataframe with the dates for the start and end of each of the 13 axhline() lines

```
fig, temp = plt.subplots()
temp.plot(df_w.index, df_w['TA_F'], color = 'red', label = 'TEMP')

# set x-label 
temp.set_xlabel('Date')
temp.tick_params('x', labelsize =24)

# set primary y label
temp.set_ylabel('Tempurature (C)')
temp.tick_params('y', colors = 'red', labelsize =24)

# set x-axis limits as the min and max of the series
temp.set_xlim(date2num([df_w.index.min(), df_w.index.max()]))
temp.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
temp.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1, month=1, day=1))

temp.set_ylim(2,28)

season = temp.twinx()

season.set_ylabel('GPP 20th percent yearly max')
season.tick_params('y', colors = 'blue', labelsize =24)

season.scatter(df_d.index, SRO_20['GPP_MINCORRECTED_20th'], marker = '^',color = 'blue')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html) instead of `axhline` if you want to use data coordinates instead of axes coordinates. Any normalization you manage to do will collapse the moment the user zooms in.